# Converting continuous to discrete data using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4

Does anyone know how to convert continuous data (in this example a raster file) into discrete data in ArcGIS Desktop?

I need to get the values from each pixel (emissivity from satellite image) into a table, so I can join them with another layer.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. There are many ways to convert raster to vector in ArcGIS. Unfortunately, your question is rather vague on what you are trying to accomplish, and doesn't give any indication of what you have tried or what error you have encountered.

Comment: Hi:) I have a raster which i calculated via raster calculator to get a general emissivity (for NDVI greater than 0,2 and smaller than 0,4). But i also have fixed values for water (negative NDVI), vegetation (greater than 0,4) and soil (0-0,2). Its only the middle part, which i had to calculate, because there is no fixed value. Now i have extracted the different "portions" of NDVI, and each part has its emissivity value in the attribute table. Unfortunately i don´t know how to join them together, because

Comment: the spatial join, merge, join tables etc. they don´t work. I extracted the different parts by Extract by Attribute..

Comment: Are you wanting to end up with a single raster that combines your 'portions'?

Comment: yes! thats what i want!:)

Comment: So, from your original NVDI you want a new raster with 3 values as follows (say): 1=soil, 2='Middle portion', 3=vegetation?

Comment: yes, i want a raster where all categories are combined, so that there is only one raster left with which i can do other calculation stuff. I already have part 1, 2 and 4 and the middle part 3 is also calculated now (so all NDVI parts have their Emissivity Value). I tried combine raster, which looked to work fine, but there are too many unique values, which creates a range from 0-255, and not a range from 0,970-0,999 (like it should be for emissivity).

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood you, you have an NDVI and you want to create a new, derived raster.  Instead of converting to multiple vector data layers, use the Raster Calculator with a nested [conditional statement](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/conditional-evaluation-with-con.htm) on the original data (scroll down to see the complex expressions):

outRast = con(ndvi <0, 1, ((ndvi <= 0.2) & (ndvi => 0), 2, ((ndvi > 0.2) & (ndvi < 0.4), 3, 4)))

This basically says:

1. if ndvi is less than 0 then outrast value is 1
2. if ndvi is between 0 and 0.2 then outrast value is 2
3. if ndvi is greater than 0.2 and less than 0.4 then outrast value is 3 (your middle portion)
4. if ndvi is greater than 0.4 then outrast value is 4

So you get your combined final raster in one step in stead of several. You will need to edit the raster algebra above to suit your exact needs but I hope you get the idea - just be careful of all those brackets!